# Android unit testing with ContentProviders and databases

Tags: android, database, unit-testing, junit, android-contentprovider

I have an app that uses a ContentProvider to serve data instead of directly accessing the database. The application is working as expected but I have a problem with unit tests: how can I force the ContentProvider to use a test database rather than a 'live' one? If I wasn't using a ContentProvider I could pass a different database name to the Constructor of my `SQLiteOpenHelper` sublass, but now the database is created with a call to onCreate() in my ContentProvider:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreate()
{
    UKMPGDataProvider.init(getContext(), Constants.DATABASE_NAME);
    return (UKMPGDataProvider.getWritableDatabase() == null) ? false : true;
}
```

As you can see, the database name is hardcoded.

Is there a way to pass a test name into the ContentProvider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of digging, I found extending ProviderTestCase2 will automatically add a prefix to the database.

Comment: So with ProviderTestCase2, is it possible for me to test MyListContactActivity behavior, without messing with the real Android Contact ContentProvider? Do you have any working testing code?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) pattern to circumvent this

Comment: Thanks Flexo, but the call to onCreate comes from the system, so I can't inject anything. I could use a public flag to specify the database name I want to create, but it doesn't seem very elegant.